# Django save different objects in a single view

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I need to render a view where I show:

- One form for the model A.
- Multiple forms for the model B. It has a FK to A.

Once the user clicks on save, the model A and all the models B should be saved. Then, the same view is rendered with the fields properly updated.

There's a special case where this view must be init with the model B forms populated with data coming from another model (C).

I'm trying to implement this view using a FormView, which renders a ModelForm for model A, and a formset for model B, with no luck. Is this the correct way to go for this scenario? What kind of formset fits better?

Comment: can you give me a reason why you need to do it, what exactly you want to create?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. You can use FormView or you could also use CreateView and UpdateView. If there are multiple forms you need to overwrite at least the four methods in the view:

1. **get** - to initialize all the needed forms and pass them to the context
2. **post** - to process the data sent by the forms (initialize the forms with self.request.POST and validate them)
3. **form_valid** - to go on with valid forms
4. **form_invalid** - to go on with invalid forms

Every object should have its ModelForm class defined (in forms.py). If there are multiple forms of one class related to an instance of another class you should use Django formsets.

You can also try to put all the logic in the form class with a minimum code in the view. That's my preferred way when using crispy_forms and I think it's shorter and cleaner. In the ModelForm class of the main class I initialize all the other forms and pass the POST data to them. Using crispy_forms I put all the forms inside the main one (using FormHelper and Layout) so that you call all of them in the template by single {% crispy form %}

The steps are:

1. Create ModelForm class for each class in forms.py
2. Create views in views.py using CreateView and UpdateView for the main class (the one the other classes relate to)
3. In the form class of the main class overwrite init method so that it initializes forms of the other related classes and puts them all inside the main for using FormHelper and Layout
4. Overwrite is_valid method in the same class so it calls is_valid on all of the forms
5. Overwrite save method in the same class so it calls save on all of the forms